# Altering Multiple Tables at once

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to alter multiple SQL Server 2008 R2 tables at one time.

This is my code:

```
use DatabaseName
go

Declare @SchemaUsed varchar(20) = 'dbo'

create table #Tables
(
  TableName varchar(100), Processed int
)

insert into #Tables 
  select top 1 table_name, 0  
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
  where TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaUsed
  and table_type = 'Base Table'
  and (TABLE_NAME like 'PM%' )
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

DECLARE @TableName varchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

WHILE EXISTS (select top 1 'x' from #Tables where Processed = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @TableName = (select top 1 TableName from #Tables where Processed = 0)

  Set @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @SchemaUsed + '.' + @TableName + ' ADD [identityID]  bigint IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL '
 -- Set @SQL =     '''' + @SQL + ''''
  Print @SQL
 EXEC  @SQL;

    update #Tables
    set Processed = 1
    where TableName = @TableName
END

drop table #Tables
```

I can't get this to work to save my life and get the following error:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: The name 'ALTER TABLE
>   dbo.PM1GTVLV ADD [identityID]  bigint IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL ' is not
>   a valid identifier.

I've also tried multiple string variations and using `sp_executesql` as well.

Can someone point out where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Instead of EXEC @sql.

As an aside, this is a much more usable version of the same code IMHO:

```
DECLARE @SchemaUsed VARCHAR(20) = 'dbo';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'ALTER TABLE ' 
 + QUOTENAME(@SchemaUsed) + '.'
 + QUOTENAME(name) + ' ADD [identityID]
   BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;'
FROM sys.tables
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) = @SchemaUsed
AND name LIKE 'PM%';

PRINT @sql;

--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Or even better:

```
DECLARE @SchemaUsed VARCHAR(20) = 'dbo';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'ALTER TABLE ' 
 + QUOTENAME(@SchemaUsed) + '.'
 + QUOTENAME(name) + ' ADD [identityID]
   BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;'
FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) = @SchemaUsed
AND name LIKE 'PM%'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns AS c
 WHERE [object_id] = t.[object_id]
 AND c.is_identity = 1);

PRINT @sql;

--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I tried the second one and it worked. I think I need to research QUOTENAME. Thanks Aaron, I owe you a drink when I see you again.

Comment: @David, from what I can tell, your error has nothing to do with `QUOTENAME`.  That said, I would agree that `sp_executesql` is often a better choice over a bare `exec`.

Comment: @Tim I was also having a hard time understanding the error - I can understand with `EXEC` but the question stated he also tried `sp_executesql`. The error there was probably about data type, not about invalid identifier, but I still prefer a version like this over cursor, temp table, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'd take a set over a loop, too. However, `exec` will work with a varchar, it's just that without the parentheses, it's trying to match that string to a stored procedure name (at least it appears that way to me).

Answer (score 1):

To execute a character string, `EXEC` requires parenthesis around the string (or character variable) as shown in the [BOL syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx):

```
EXEC (@SQL);
```