# Add identity increment property to existing tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple tables in database all table has id column which is primary key.

I want a script by which i can add identity property to all tables at once rather than I go and change one by one.

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: What RDBMS's are you using? Postgres, Oracle, MySQL, DB2, etc

Comment: i am using Sql server 2008 r2
My question is :

I Have multiple tables in database with no data 

Only Tables Are Created

Now i want is .. All table should have auto identity property
without doing manually on each table 

i want a script with loop which will check all tables and auto identity property should be assinged

Answer (score 0):

> You can't alter the existing columns for identity.
>
> You have 2 options:

1. Create a new table with identity & drop the existing table
2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column

> But take spl care when these columns have any constraints / relations.
>
> For already craeted table `Names`

```
        Drop table Names
        Create table Names
        (
                    ID int,
                    Name varchar(50)
        )

        Insert Into Names Values(1,'SQL Server')
        Insert Into Names Values(2,'ASP.NET')
        Insert Into Names Values(4,'C#')
```

> In this Approach you can retain the existing data values on the newly
>   created identity column

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Names
            (
            Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
            Name varchar(50) NULL
            )  ON [PRIMARY]

go
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names ON

go
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Names)
            INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Names (Id, Name)
                        SELECT Id, Name FROM dbo.Names TABLOCKX

go
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names OFF

go
DROP TABLE dbo.Names

go

Exec sp_rename 'Tmp_Names', 'Names'
```

> In this approach you can’t retain the existing data values on the
>   newly created identity column;
>
> The identity column will hold the sequence of number

```
Alter Table Names Add Id_new Int Identity(1,1)
Go

Alter Table Names Drop Column ID
Go

Exec sp_rename 'Names.Id_new', 'ID','Column'
```

[Source 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032/how-to-alter-column-to-identity11?forum=transactsql)

---

> What you can do is write a quick query to generate the SQL for you
>   like so:

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT 
CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8;") 
AS MySQLCMD FROM TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_schema_goes_here";
```

> Then you can run the output from this to do what you need.

[Source 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35073/modify-all-tables-in-a-database-with-a-single-command)

**EDIT**

You could check [Altering Multiple Tables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456523/altering-multiple-tables-at-once)

Comment: Thank you Stanislovas Kalašnikovas.. but this is not what i need
i really appreciate your answer

Comment: i already have blank tables contain no data in it 

and all tables have id column which i want to make primary key as well as need to assign identity insert property....but i dont want to do it manually by going and assinig it ..that i know how to do it 

I need a script by which i can loop and assign property to all tables

Comment: Check for the link in my answer, in edit section. This is what you need, should work for you.